How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms?
If physicalism is true, everything is physical. Minds are physical. Thoughts are physical. Emotions are physical. Consciousness is physical. And when it comes to abstract ideas, such as logic and mathematics, either they do not exist (they are illusions or fictions) or they exist but in some physical form.
So, suppose physicalism is true. How would a physicalist interpret the statement "theorem X is true"? Let's take X as the Pythagorean theorem as an example. If the statement "the Pythagorean theorem is true" is factually true of reality, and since everything is physical, the theorem must be physically true. But exactly how? What does it mean for a theorem to be physically true under physicalism?
For example, under physicalism, is the original, raw statement "theorem X is true" (a generic abstract statement) translated into a collection of concrete physical statements that can be empirically verified against physical reality?

Related questions

Existence of abstract objects for a physicalist
Can a physicalist be also realist about mathematical objects?
Since mathematicians are physical beings, does this mean that mathematics ultimately reduces to physics?
Is a priori (non-empirical-evidence-based) mathematical knowledge possible under reductive physicalism?
How can one believe that mathematical assertions are objectively true while denying the existence of mathematical objects?


Already a close-vote as opinion-based, even though I'm clearly narrowing the scope to physicalism and asking an answer from that perspective ...

I haven't downvoted or vtc but I have to say questions like this: > How do idealists explain our lack of consciousness when we sleep?"


How do physicalists interpret mathematical theorems? That ask a person to step into another person's shoes to think like a physicalist walks a tightrope between legitimacy and opinion. Anyone who is not a card-carrying physicalist has no business answering this question. Anyone else is offering their opinion based on their understanding of physicalism.



Only when physicalism can perfectly explain the mental existence of abstract objects like a perfect circle which obviously doesn't exist mentally from sense perceptions in the always fractal physical world, mathematical theorems can be reduced to physicalist terms perfectly just like a pure circle...

Presumably in the same way they explain the existence of ideas in general, whatever that is.

I suppose the idea of a unicorn is incompatible with the idea of decorating its third horn.

@user80226 you just have to accept that people may close your question even if they don’t have a valid reason for it. The good thing is how popular or unpopular something is has nothing to do with the truth. P.S. it’s interesting how my comment outlining this was removed earlier, but not any comments that want to close your question.

A mathematical theorem may be true in the sense that it follows logically from some set of mathematical axioms. We can verify whether those axioms (and the theorem itself) correspond to how reality actually works by considering the evidence, doing experiments or using reasoning.
For example, we could check whether putting one thing next to another thing gives 2 things, which would suggest 1 + 1 = 2 corresponds to reality (although that may be a flawed example, given that what "a thing" is is not as obvious considering things consist of and intermingle with other things). We can also build theories on top of those axioms to model behaviour of things in the physical world, and then testing the accuracy of those models by predicting future behaviour (or past behaviour) and seeing if our predictions are correct.
The problem of "aboutness" / intentionality?

How mental states can be about something? How can a physical brain have any content at all?

That answer might be blurring the line between valid "frame challenge" and simply trying to make an argument against the premise of the question. But I digress.
I'd say computers and AI probably definitively killed/invalidated the problem of "aboutness".
When ChatGPT is responding in relation to some concept, how can 1s and 0s be "about" that concept?
I'm not a proponent of computationalism, but it's a similar question to asking the same about the brain (ChatGPT still has some internal state, even if it probably isn't conscious, and its text output itself could be said to be "about" something). And we definitively know that ChatGPT reduces to 1s and 0s and electricity and such, because we built it.
But if someone doesn't think consciousness reduces to brain activity, then they'd probably reject this as disanalogous.
They might say ChatGPT's state isn't "about" anything, or its output is "about" things under a different definition of the word or something. But then one might ask what exactly "about" means here.
Maybe there's potential for a fruitful discussion down that route. But on the surface, the problem of aboutness is only really a problem if you start off with some non-physical or mystical ideas of consciousness.

But what is a "mathematical axiom" physically in the first place? Where can I find it physically in physical reality? In other words, what does it mean ontologically for an axiom to exist under physicalism?

@user80226 it exists in the sense that in every possible physical world, the statement 2+2=4 is true. One may think of necessary mathematical truths as “attributes” of physical worlds.

@Syed But 2+2=4 itself needs to be parsed into something physical, since numbers do not exist as abstract Platonic ideas under physicalism. Thus, would 2+2=4 mean something like "every time a physical brain counts 2 physical objects and another 2 physical objects, it would also count 4 physical objects"?

@user80226 does the attribute of length, shape, mass need to be parsed into something physical?

@Syed Once you reach the fundamental ontology posited by physicalism, no, since you have reached the bottom of physical reality.

@user80226 Axioms don't exist. They correspond to how reality works (or they don't). Somewhat like how an image of an animal may or may not correspond to a real animal (putting aside the fact that an image itself may have a physical existence, and that our thoughts about an axiom has a physical existence).

@NotThatGuy Would you mind adding something about "aboutness" mentioned in Philomath's answer?

@user80226 Edited.

@user80226 But then one might ask what exactly "about" means here. That is exactly the problem. If nobody ever reads the ChatGPT output, does it still mean anything? It translates to the Searle's Chinese Room argument. Does ChatGPT understand Chinese? For the record, I am a hard physicalist, so I don't attribute any special status to human brains...

@Philomath "If nobody ever reads the ChatGPT output, does it still mean anything" - If no-one hears you talk, do your thoughts mean anything? If you automate ChatGPT / an LLM and make it do things in the external world by connecting it to other services (as people are doing), does that make it mean something? Whether ChatGPT "understands" Chinese has the same problem of "aboutness" of using a vague term some may define as inherently dependent on consciousness or the non-physical. ChatGPT is similar to Chinese Room, but it's a real-life demonstration of thought-like things generated physically.

@NotThatGuy I am sorry for the confusion. My question was of course if nobody ever reads the ChatGPT output, does it still mean anything, that is, does ChatGPT itself mean anything to say with it. Obviously, we will agree that meaning exists in human brains. The question is whether, and how, it can render meaning to itself. If you automate an LLM and make it do stuff, it will of course mean something in your mind and in the minds of others, but does the LLM mean to say anything? I understand the language is ambiguous here.(1/2)

@NotThatGuy I use the term "aboutness" because the technical term intentionality gets misunderstood often. Intentionality is used in over 330 entries in the Stanford Enyclopedia of Philosophy and has its own dedicated entry there. Anything but vague. Your argument against the Chinese Room is one of scale and sophistication. If we make the Chinese Room much larger with many (millions) of employees and very complicated algorithms to produce beautiful philosophical treatises in Chinese, will it then really understand Chinese? (2/2)

@NotThatGuy By the way, I am a hardcore physicalist, so I agree a lot with what you say. I just think that this intentionality problem needs an explanation, just as much for human brains as for AI or AGI. It needs a pysical explanation to defend physicalism. (3/2 sic)

@Philomath "Obviously, we will agree that meaning exists in human brains" - by some definition, sure. But in what sense? We intuitively understand what is meant by "meaning" and "understanding". But we lack a firm enough grasp of those concepts to say whether AI has it. What's funny about the Chinese room is there's probably still a sense of understanding there somewhere. Maybe someone who understands is telling the agent what to do. Maybe the agent themselves understand the rules of converting input symbols to output symbols, even if they don't have a reference for the symbols themselves. ...

@Philomath ... If ChatGPT could be said to understand anything (if we don't just say understanding entails consciousness), it would probably not be the references for the words, but rather it may be understanding which words follow on other words. It's arguably far better at that than humans are, who don't just understand that by itself, but rather builds that understanding on top of an understanding of the references for the words and grammar rules, as well as reasoning and such. One may say that leads to more accurate results, but the pure chaining-based understanding is arguably worse. ...

@Philomath ... Imagine humans trying to do what ChatGPT does and have extended coherent interactions in a language where they lack references for the words and lack grammar understanding. Do you think they'd be able to produce output that matches or exceeds the quality of what ChatGPT produces? I have my doubts. My point is that I don't see a categorical difference in understanding between ChatGPT and humans, except in terms of whether there is conscious experience, to be aware of said understanding.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is a problem that ultimately leads back to the much more generic problem of intentionality.
This is sometimes translated as aboutness. It is the problem how mental states can be about something. In other words, intentionality is the fact that mental states can have mental representation or mental content.
When you ask a question like: What does it mean for a theorem to be physically true under physicalism?, you first have to answer the much more basic question of how can a physical brain have any content (like the concept of a theorem) at all? Otherwise, you keep asking questions (as in the comments of an other answer) Under physicalism, what is 5, what is 12, what is an axiom?. Or indeed, under physicalism, what is a theorem?
I think this problem of aboutness is often overlooked, but it is a fundamental problem for the physicalist view. How can matter, brains, neurons, and ultimately, atoms and molecules, be about something?

Little aside: I think the term intentionality is one of the most infelicitous terms in philosophy because it is easily confused with other words like intention and intension. I usually think about it in terms of aboutness...

Part of the problem here is the definition of physical. It is possible to argue that since the hardware the idea exists upon is in the physical world, whether that hardware is paper or a brain, that instance of the idea is physically present. The fact that the idea can be copied / cloned into a new medium does not invalidate this. But many people seem to reject it because they can't yet examine the mental representation at a physical level. Since absence of proof is not proof of absence, this winds up at becoming a matter of personal convictions, and will remain so pending proof either way.

@keshlam, I think that you confuse the idea being present with "intentionality/aboutness". Many ideas physically exist in computer's memory, yet computers don't have any understanding over them, they just follow instructions operating over these physical representations. So one has to separate any physical representation of an idea and the idea itself. In that sense, an idea cannot be physical or you must believe that there are no actual ideas, only some physical stuff other physical stuff interacts with. idk how can you explain the idea that there is such thing as an idea though in such case.

@akostadinov: The distinction you are trying to draw only makes sense to a non-physicalist. There is only physical stuff. Some of that physical stuff is energy. Some of that energy interacts with physical stuff to create standing patterns of energy. Some of those standing patterns are a biological. Some of those biological patterns equate to programs and data storage. The fact that we cannot easily observe them that way does not refute this point of view. The fact that there are timing and/or stochastic elements to the way they are processed does not refute this point of view.

@keshlam, again, it is fine to accept that there are unobservable patterns of matter, energy or whatever you consider physical. It is alright that some stuff interacts with other stuff. Giving any kind of meaning to these though is outside just a physical pattern. Just your statement "There is only physical stuff.", that implies there is non-physical stuff that is not. But then this "non-physical stuff" is what we are discussing. So in some form it "is" such that we can discuss it. Which is a contradiction to that same statement meaning it cannot be true.

The question is whether you consider patterns of chemical and electrical energy running in the physical world to be physical or not. I would group them with physical. Apparently you don't. That's fine, but it doesn't change my answer.

@keshlam Are you familiar with Searle's thought experiment of the Chinese room?

@philomath: I'd need to review it to be sure I was remembering it accurately. But as I (mis)remember, the conclusion was that conflicting guesses about what was happening inside the room were equally well supported until we looked inside.  Which tells us nothing about other rooms or whether/when looking inside might become possible. We've recently been able to extract recognizable audio from a brain scan of someone listening to music. I expect the tools to continue to improve, and I don't expect them to show anything but the physical is needed. Others believe otherwise. Shrug.

@keshlam Maybe review it. ;) I think aboutness is for you what water is for a fish. A fish swims in water but doesn't realise it even exists. Mind you, I am as much a physicalist as you are, but I think this problem of intentionality needs an explanation.

@philomath: I freely admit I don't grok the aboutness/intentionality thing. Ok, I have homework.  Are these terms used in Serle's experiment, or are there additional readings? Pointers to good references welcome.

@philomath: Reviewed Serle. Doesn't convince me. May be true for z a fully deterministic system, but any programmer knows that non-deterministic emergent behaviors arise as software and hardware complexity increase, especially in lossy timing-dependent massively parallel processing. And if the room retains state of the conversation, and is self-training, I believe that is sufficient to effectively achieve awareness. Basically, his argument relies on a specific, particularly limited, implementation, and I think his model is flat out wrong. At most charitable, the argument is outdated.

I still don't grok intentionality or aboutness. Looking for a reference for those.

@keshlam So you think the room understands Chinese? Or since the room is from 1980, we could ask the same question for an LLM.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@keshlam Yeah, I know about LLMs and the fact that they are basically matrix multiplications simulating networks in Python written code on a Von Neumann architecture... The hallucinations are interesting and there are links with the 'free energy prinicple' of Karl Friston and the 'reality as a controlled hallucinations' idea of Anil Seth. I think somewhere there is the way forward to understanding ...

Moved my additional thoughts to the chat. You're right, we are far beyond reasonably use of comments.

@keshlam, "The question is whether you consider patterns of chemical and electrical energy running in the physical world to be physical or not. I would group them with physical. Apparently you don't.", I never said that and actually I group them as physical. You're bringing the question to that point and not address the actual issue. Which is of aboutness/awareness/consciousness. Which you explain with other concepts and more concepts and more concepts. And never translate this to the concept-less just physical stuff according to your theory.

I am confident that when we understand the brain better we will be able to bring it to the purely physical. For now, we simply do not have that level of detail available. I am confident in projecting that we will. Others feel otherwise. If you are looking for incontrovertible proof, I haven't got it, but there's no proof for the alternatives either. In the absence of other criteria to decide upon, I am comfortable with resorting to Occam's razor for selecting my preferred answer. I reserve the right to be wrong.


What does it mean for a theorem to be physically true under physicalism?

There is no specific concept of "physically true". Physicalists don't use a concept like that. If so, the question is:

What does it mean for a theorem to be true under physicalism?

A mathematical theorem is true if it can be proven based on given axioms. This means that when a proof is presented to you, and you are a rational agent, and you're not suffering from certain serious neurological conditions and you understand the language, you have the right level of education, etc., etc., you will also see that it indeed is what we decided to call a proof.
If someone wants to push the physicalist view -- claiming that "everything is physical" -- it's possible (not incoherent) to claim that a mathematical theorem is true if and only if it is accepted as valid by some agents after those agents processed a sequence of signs that is called a "proof". Alternatively, in a somewhat different interpretation of physicalism, truth could be defined as the ideal limit -- as what all rational agents would ultimately agree on, if they would see and get enough time to understand  a proof. But anyway, any statement in the form "p is true" could be construed to mean "I accept statement p as valid" or "we (some concrete community of agents) accept statement p as valid". Which in turn can be construed to be equivalent to "I (or we) will generate a sequence of signs that we call a proof of p, and that we perceive as proof of p, if you ask me (us) for it". (We could also complete that with "And in sofar as you are intelligent enough, and capable and willing to first work through the following preliminary exercises (...), we are extremely confident that you will also perceive this as proof. And if you wonder what the physicalist basis is for this confidence, we simply point you to the empirical fact of the actual agreement among mathematicians, which surpasses the width of agreement in any other field.")
Now -- from a physicalist point of view -- all these statements about math and physicalism here would then also "only" be true, if or in sofar as they are accepted as true by some agent. Indeed, but that doesn't lead to any obvious contradictions or paradoxes. At least, none that I see...

This answer focuses more on how to establish the truth of a mathematical theory, not what it means for one to exist (or not even exist) in a physicalist worldview.

What it means for a truth to exist? I don't think it makes sense in any theory to say that truths "exist" (except in the form of beliefs, theories or represented facts). The question was what it means for sth to be true. What this means in physicalism, as I understand it, is that sth is accepted as correct or valid, in other words, that sth is believed as fact. In math this can be strengthened to: a proof (which is just a sequences of symbols) has been constructed and has been accepted as proof.

I meant the mathematical theory to exist, not the truth to exist. @mudskipper

The mathematical theory exists in the brains of people. It also exists in the form of texts, sequences of signs that will be used and interpreted by people in predictable ways.

An idea, like a fact, is not physical.
But it exists in the physical framework that it is encoded in. That can be paper, computer, or brain. And it can be copied from one medium to another by equally various mechanisms.
Whether you consider it part of the physical world is up to you, but it does not require what is commonly called non-physicality any more than any other pattern of energy maintained by a physical substrate does. And energy is physical, especially since Einstein.

The same way that they explain consciousness: by arguing that it supervenes upon physical reality. Mathematical theories would then be theories that are ultimately grounded in physical reality, even if they are not equivalent to physical reality.
One of the main responses, highlighted in the SEP summarizes this:

One response points out that, while the problem of abstracta confronts many different versions of physicalism, it does not arise for supervenience physicalism. After all, since numbers exist in all possible worlds, facts about them trivially supervene on the physical; any world identical to the actual world in physical respects will be identical to it in respect of whether 5+7=12, because any world at all is identical to the actual world in that respect!

However, responses to this are paramount and are included within the same article, as is the nature of philosophy.

"Mathematical theories would then be theories that are ultimately grounded in physical reality" - But how? Give me an example.

"whether 5+7=12" - Under physicalism, what is 5? What is 7? What is 12? What is +?

@user80226 I believe the physicalist would argue that 5 and 7 do not exist but as language that describe the inner workings of the physical world.

If that's true, then all mathematical knowledge is empirical under physicalism, since everything comes from physics, which is empirical. Mathematics is just a particular case of what's possible according to the laws of physics.

You answered @user80226' question by just moving the problem to other concepts. What does it mean to "work", what is a "language", how can anything have any meaning to anything? But you cannot answer these questions without using concepts that themselves can be questioned in the same way.
